# calling js function from jsrender template code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender

I'm using jsrender as javascript template in my view. I have issue with date since I'm getting data as json. MyTime property is displayed like this

```
/Date(1395927615038)/
```

So I've tried with js function which converts date like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function convertDate(jsonDate) {
                var a = jsonDate.match(/\d+/);
                var fdate = parseInt(a);
                var date = new Date(fdate);
                return date;               
            };
        </script>
```

I'm calling this function from my template on the same page like this

```
<li>Time: {{:convertDate(Time)}} </li>
```

Error occured when calling this function

> Error: data.convertDate is not a function.

p.s. if it's matters at all, function convertDate is loaded before template code.

Comment: which kind of template engine do you use?

Comment: @Vasil Vanchuk jsrender

Comment: According API you can't use functions in templates, if they aren't methods of data parameter. So you can send function as parametr, or better calculate date before passing value to the renderer